# to validate user input of phone number and keep on asking till ser press exit

Tags: java

the number is expected to be a string of 10 digits, while they could in these formats: 2047773333, (204)777-3333, or 204-777-333. Your program should output "It is valid" if the 10 digits are in these three formats. Otherwise, it should output "It is invalid". Your program should keep asking user to input the phone number until the user types in (exactly) "exit". 
I don't know how to do it was asked in an interview..
i had to do it using structures and classes

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class A3Q2{

public static void main(String[] Args){
    System.out.println("Enter Phone Number=");
    Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
    String s=kb.next();
    while(s!="exit")
    {
    for(int i=0 ;s.length<11;i++)
    {
        if(Character.isdigit(s)){
            System.out.println("Valid Input");
        }

         for(int i=0;i<13;i++){
             if(String. CharAt(index)=='('&& String. CharAt(index)==')'){

            System.out.println("Valid Input");
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<12;i++){
        if(String.charAt(index)=='-'){
            System.out.println("Valid Input");
        }
    }
}
 System.out.println("Enter Phone Number=");
 String s=kb.next();
```

}

System.out.println("End of Program");

```
 }


    }
```

Comment: Do you have a specific programming related question?

Comment: Read about Regular Expressions

Comment: if you are speaking about validating a phone number, the first thing that pops into my mind is to use a regular expression something like this (^[2-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$) now, how you make a regex validation depends on the language you are using, maybe you need a class or not but I recommend to keep that as simple as possible. Most high level languages already come with check functions for this kind of things.

Comment: can you code out the exact solution just using classes and control structures not using array

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use java regular expressions. I've solved a similar problem in class using regular expressions. The user had to enter the correct password format or I keep prompting them until the correct format was entered...
Check out this link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/